# How to properly configure Guzzle to download zip files from other servers

Tags: php, http-status-code-400, guzzle6

This function is meant to download .zip files

```
function download($url, $debug = false)
{
    $client = new Client([
        'connect_timeout' => 10,
        'timeout' => 60.0,
        'debug' => $debug
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
    try {
        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $response->getBody()->getContents();
        }

    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        //var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
        $txt = json_encode(['log_error' => $e->getResponse(), 'response' => $response->getBody()->getContents(), 'url' => $url]);
        file_put_contents(storage_path() . '/logs-etiquetas/log-' . microtime(true) . '-' . auth()->user()->company_id . '.txt', $txt);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting error below

> production_ERROR: Client error: `GET https: //api.mercadolibre.com/shipment_labels? shipment_ids = 27868452659,27864682043,27168438675,27868264704,27868866716,27868738288,27867965828 & response_type = zpl2 & caller.id = 23264143 & access_token = 400 Bad Request` response:
>   bad_request

Comment: It seems You didn't submit an access token. Did You previously login?

Comment: All the requested data is correct, I removed from the post not to expose the data of the clients.

Comment: Did You try to `url_encode` the url before transmitting?

Comment: No, I'm going to test this alternative

Comment: "cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'https%3A%2F%2Fapi.mercadolibre.com%2Fshipment_labels%3Fshipment_ids%3D27868497406%26response_type%3Dzpl2%26caller.id%3D18960642%26access_token%3DAPP_USR-48344990271235443-022410-d00c0e6684cc4426d49354c8cedff0fa-98860642' (see //curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"